# Managed Devices with Work Profile: How to be qualified to read privileged device identifiers

Tags: android, mdm, emm, android-work-profile

Being an EMM organization, we have an application that provides a device owner and a user's work profile enrollment of their devices.

As an MDM application, we must manage the device information by accessing privileged identifiers. Since Android 11, we can access these identifiers in the Device Owner enrollments but not in the work profile enrollments. How do we qualify to read privileged device identifiers in the user's work profile enrollment?

Answer (score 0):

I want to share the response that I received in the Android Discussion Forum:

> Since work profiles set up on a personally owned device will no longer
> be granted access to the device's hardware identifiers (IMEI, MEID,
> serial number) in [Android 12](https://emm.androidenterprise.dev/s/article/Android-12-Impact-Device-Identifiers), **there is currently no way for you
> to have a special privilege to access these identifiers**. We suggest
> you leverage the [enrollment-specific ID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#getEnrollmentSpecificId()). The enrollment-specific
> ID remains stable across factory resets when re-enrolled to the same
> organization managed by the same device policy application.    Here is
> the [**link**](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids#best-practices-android-identifiers) for best practices for working with Android
> identifiers.